# Можно ли как-то изменить окно нотификации в Windows вызываемое с помощью Java?

Tags: java

Я знаю как выводить простые оповещения с помощью TrayIcon на подобие этого:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос в следующем: можно ли как-то кастомизировать вот это окно нотификации с помощью Java? Можно ли добавить кнопки или еще какие-нибудь компоненты?

Например, как получить что-то вроде этого?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [toast content](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/adaptive-interactive-toasts)

Comment: @user7860670, спасибо за наводку